# What motherboard spec should i look for using 4 displays

Tags: gpu

I am not sure if i am on the right forum. Let me know where to go if i'm wrong.

I have an **ASUS** mATX motherboard **H110M2** and **PNY Quardro P620**. Initially I put it into a mini tower which only had a **450W** power unit. When I connect my fourth screen to my P620, I could either had 800x600 resolution or the fourth screen is not detected at all. For a such low resolution. I thought it's my TV having a low resolution or the HDMI cable was faulty.

One day I moved my H110M2 to a full tower which had 500W power. My fourth screen connects without any hassle and obtained a full 1960 x 1280 resolution. I realised it's something to do with power.

Because I didn't have the GPU bracket for the full tower, I kept changing cases, plugging and unplugging my graphic card, etc. But finally when I moved my motherboard back to my mini tower, the board is certified dead. It doesn't turn on any more. As I remember before it died, the P620 stopped working first. When I displayed out from my motherboard directly, my screen had a moment of smears of dots appearing and stripes appeared in the middle of the screen. I guess something burnt from that moment. When I turned off my computer, it never returned.

Does somebody figure what happened? Is that the m-ATX motherboard just unable to output 4 displays or the power is too high for the motherboard?

I am planning to buy a new motherboard but I tend to get an m-ATX rather than a full ATX. What specs should I look at if I want it fully support outputting 4 displays?

Comment: Your motherboard has no idea what the graphics card is doing. It's unlikely that the MB *specifically* was the problem. The TDP (power draw) of that card is rated at 40W, which is lower than I'd expect for something that wants to output to 4 monitors. It could be the card overloaded the motherboard. I'd look for a card with its own power connector.

Comment: if the graphic card overloaded the motherboard, it will burn the motherboard? i thought worst case would be not detecting my screen?

Comment: my motherboard didn't shout for pain, itch or any discomfort and gone dead straight....

Comment: Since using the same setup with a different power supply "fixed" the problem, that means it was the power supply. To little power can be just as bad as to much power. The power supply itself is likely no longer working correctly. The power supply itself should be removed and not used. Power supplies almost never just "die" they will keep working in a diminished capacity. Using a known bad power supply with a known good motherboard is begging for disaster since after the power supply components start to degrade beyond a certain point the power supply can spike. So replace that power supply.

Comment: i want to know if i make the GPU wobble while the power is on (because i didn't have a full tower bracket and plugged in DP cables for testing) will burn my motherboard?